# How can i solve these line at sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create database test;
on primary
 (Name = tt, FileName = 'E:\Sql Course\test\tt.mdf')
 log on
  (Name = ttt, FileName = 'E:\Sql Course\test\tt.ldf')
```

when I write these code to create the database, these error appears:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'

& I can't solve it

Answer (score 1):

You have a redundant semi-colon (`;`) before your `on` clause. Just drop it:

```
create database test 
on primary (Name = tt, FileName = 'E:\Sql Course\test\tt.mdf') 
log on (Name = ttt, FileName = 'E:\Sql Course\test\tt.ldf')
```

Comment: when I delete Semi-colon & write like your code...these error appear

Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Directory lookup for the file "E:\Sql Course\test\tt.mdf" failed with the operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Comment: Try to use `'E:\SqlCourse\test\tt.mdf'` (without space) instead of `'E:\Sql Course\test\tt.mdf'`. Don't forget to move the physical files to the new corresponding folder.